# how to calculate distance between two points in google maps?

Tags: google-maps

how can i calculate the distance between two points in google maps, where i know the latitude and longtutude of two points ..

i don't want to use google direction api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two GLatLngs, you can use this:

```
var miledistance, kmdistance;

miledistance = glatlng1.distanceFrom(glatlng2, 3959).toFixed(1);
kmdistance = (miledistance * 1.609344).toFixed(1);
```

If you have the lat, lngs as floats you can just create some GLatLng's to use this method.. eg

```
var miledistance, kmdistance;

miledistance = new GLatLng(lat1,lng1).distanceFrom(new GLatLng(lat2, lng2), 3959).toFixed(1);
kmdistance = (miledistance * 1.609344).toFixed(1);
```

Duncan.